# UE4 physics incorrect volume

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm currently trying to develop/learn unreal engines physics while making a sailing game. I have a current issue that the "physics" of the boat feels like they are being slow motioned/ have incorrect volume.
Explanation/ example:

When a wave hits the boat rises with the wave, but when one of the boat parts hangs above the water it should drop.

**Example of what I mean:**

[image]

**The issue examples straight from engine:**
[image]
[image]

**Blueprint of the boat.**

Movement:

[image]

Buoyancy setup:

[image]

Would change the centre of mass fix this issue? Or is this related to buoyancy pushing the boat from the water?

Comment: Have you tried moving the bottom of the ship's collider to the level of the cannons? So the ship will be half in the water and, perhaps, the problem will be solved.

Comment: [A little higher than here](https://ic.pics.livejournal.com/66sean99/13114510/1071653/1071653_original.jpg)

Comment: Send a beam from the center of the ship down to the water every second. Get normal(FHitResult.Normal), calculate required angle (90 - (arccos((Normal.x * ShipMotionVector.x + Normal.y * ShipMotionVector.y + Normal.z * ShipMotionVector.z)/(Normal.Length() * ShipMotionVector.Length())))) and within 5 seconds using FMath::Lerp turn the ship to the obtained angle (There may be inaccuracies).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion I will try that!

Comment: Normal -> ImpactNormal

Comment: The points of buoyancy is set correctly https://prnt.sc/26db7iq

The issue is I believe in weight / how gravity works. I will try your second suggestion